# Filter out the format [n] from a string in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Hey guys I'm relatively new to Haskell and I'm trying to return the number of references of the format `[n]` from a string.

For example  `let x = "blah blah [1] blah blah [1] blah blah [2]"` should return `3` since the function would see that there are three references in this function. I'm having trouble trying to match against `[n]` since `n` can be any number. I have tried things such as `filter([_])` but had no luck.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When you encounter a problem show what you've already tried. If the functions compiled/type-check, show their output, and what you actually expected as output. This will demonstrate the problem to possible posters better. Also, [use markdown to format your post](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can quite easily achieve your goal with standard Haskell alone. The general name for this kind of task is *parsing*, but at least for such simple grammars that amounts mostly *pattern matching* on string-heads. Very easy because Haskell strings are just lists of characters!

First, think about what signature you want.

```
extractBracketNums :: String -> [Integer]
```

seems a good idea. If you only want to *count* them, the result type could as well be a single `Int`, but if you actually output the list of numbers you keep the function more generally useful, and it's trivial to obtain the count afterwards with `length`.

Now, to implement this we need three cases:

```
extractBracketNums "" = []
```

this is just the base case, ensuring that any recursion we do will safely terminate when the string has been fully consumed. Nothing in the string means, no bracketed numbers either!

```
extractBracketNums ('[':r) = ...
```

This is the interesting case: we've found an opening bracket, it *might* be the beginning of a number!

Before actually implementing that case, we need to consider one more:

```
extractBracketNums (_:r) = extractBracketNums
```

This means: a (sub-) string that doesn't begin with an opening bracket is uninteresting for us, so just discard any such character.

Now for the interesting case: we need to check that after the opening bracket comes a number, and only a number, before the bracket is closed again. So, we need to try to *split off* a number from the beginning of the remaining string. This can be done quite well with the [`span`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:span) function. Its signature is `(a->Bool) -> [a] -> ([a],[a])`, so for us `(Char->Bool) -> String -> (String,String)`. It takes a *predicate on characters*, which should determine whether a character is possibly part of a number-string. The module `Data.Char` has [that exact function](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=isNumber) available.

```
extractBracketNums ('[':r) = case span isNumber r of
    ...
```

so now we need to decide if we really found a number, and nothing else. If we *didn't*  find a number right at the beginning, then `span` will immediately fail, i.e. give an empty string as its first result.

```
extractBracketNums ('[':r) = case span isNumber r of
                              ([],_) -> extractBracketNums r
```

i.e., in this case I just forget about the opening bracket since it doesn't contain (only) a number. Same plan if we do find a number but not a closing bracket immediately after it (we'll cover that one in the end) but if we *do* find a closing bracket directly after the split off number, we can take that number, convert it from string to `Integer`, prepend it to any possible other numbers yet to be found. And be happy.

```
                              (num,']':r') -> read num : extractBracketNums r'
```

Now the completing case (did find some number, but no closing bracket after it): this also means we'll simply forget about the opening bracket.

```
                              (_,_) -> extractBracketNums r
```

So, all together:

```
import Data.Char (isNumber)

extractBracketNums :: String -> [Integer]
extractBracketNums "" = []
extractBracketNums ('[':r) = case span isNumber r of
                              ([],_) -> extractBracketNums r
                              (num,']':r') -> read num : extractBracketNums r'
                              (_,_) -> extractBracketNums r
extractBracketNums (_:r) = extractBracketNums r
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use [`Text.Regex.Posix`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-posix-0.95.2/docs/Text-Regex-Posix.html) for that:

```
\> import Text.Regex.Posix ((=~))
\> let txt = "blah blah [1] blah blah [1] blah blah [2]"
\> let pat = "\\[[0-9]+\\]"  -- regular expression pattern to match
\> txt =~ pat :: Int
3
```

The function `=~` is *overloaded on return type*; for example if you want to see what matched, you use the exact same function call with different type annotation:

```
\> txt =~ pat :: [[String]]
[["[1]"],["[1]"],["[2]"]]
```

Comment: *"Hey guys im relatively new to Haskell"*. You're going to need a whole lot more explanation.